# How to differentiate pre-filled input and entered input in a input box using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<input id="text1" />
<input id="text2" />
```

I want to retrieve data from database for input with id(text1) and enter data manually in input with id(text2)
Can JavaScript understand difference between these two values once the input is filled?

```html
<input id="text1" />
<input id="text2" />
```

This is the code I have, and I want to differentiate between the entries coming from the database and manually entered entries using JavaScript, is there any way to do this using vanilla JS?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're asking. What do you mean by _"can JavaScript understand difference between these two values"_? Of course it can using plain old string comparison

Comment: Also, I have to ask... your [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74929571/1) didn't format the code so it was visible. Could you not see that parts of your question were missing before posting it? Were you not shown a preview of how it would look?

Comment: What do you mean by "*retrieve data from database*"? Which code retrieves what data from the database, does it happen in the js in the browser or on the server that generates the html? And for what reason do you want to distinguish them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between value and defaultValue for a text input in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861166/difference-between-value-and-defaultvalue-for-a-text-input-in-javascript)

Comment: See also [How to get difference of changed input value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66427364/215552)

Answer (score 1):

The OP could use the input element's `defaultValue` property for detecting form controls with a set default (a value which is part of the element's initially rendered markup).

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('[type="text"]')
  .forEach(elm => elm.value = 'overwritten content');

document
  .querySelectorAll('[type="text"]')
  .forEach(({ value, defaultValue }) =>
    console.log({ value, defaultValue })
  );
```

```html
<input type="text" value="foo bar baz"/>
<input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you fill data, store it in a variable that will temporarily store its value to check against the changed value. The pseudo-code might look something like this.

```
var temp = await fetch(from db)
// Display this in the field and set up an onchange listener on the other field
onChange(e){
    if(temp !== e.target.value) console.log("This is not same")
}
```